# scrapy Crawled 405

Tags: scrapy, http-status-code-405

```py
start_urls = ['https://www.qichacha.com/search?key=北京证大向上']
def parse(self, response):
    # the start_url is a list page, the company_url is a detail_url from the list page
    yield scrapy.Request(url=company_url, meta={"infos":info},callback=self.parse_basic_info, dont_filter=True)
```

when request the company_url, then response 405,
but, if i use

```py
response = requests.get(company_url, headers=headers)
print(response.code)
print(response.txt)
```

then response 200 and can parse the html page, or

```py
start_urls=[company_url]
def parse(self, response):
    print(response.code)
    print(response.txt)
```

and also response 200,I don't know why response 405
when it response 405,i print request like this:
{'_encoding': 'utf-8', 'method': 'GET', '_url': 'https://www.qichacha.com/firm_b18bf42ee07d7961e91a0edaf1649287.html', '_body': b'', 'priority': 0, 'callback': None, 'errback': None, 'cookies': {}, 'headers': {b'User-Agent': [b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1036.7 Safari/535.20']}, 'dont_filter': False, '_meta': {'depth': 1}, 'flags': []}
what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the page blocks Scrapy using the default user-agent string. Running the spider like this works for me:

```
scrapy runspider -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36" spider.py
```

Alternatively, you can set `USER_AGENT` in your project's `settings.py`. Or, use something like [scrapy-fake-useragent](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent) to handle this automatically.

Comment: I used this way but always response 405, and i used the UserAgentMiddleware to auto change user_agent